# JavaScript: How does true >> 0 = 1?

Tags: javascript, boolean, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have been looking around for an answer but, all I could find was why

```
true == 1 = true  
false == 0 = true
```

I still don't understand how JavaScript takes a `Boolean` type and adds it to an `int` type

```
true >> 0 = 1 
false >> 1 = 0
```

Comment: There are a lot of operators in your question title. Depending on how they are interpreted by the user, they could cause confusion. Could you adjust it to make it clearer?

Comment: `true` is converted to Number ==> **1** and shift right by 0 means do nothing. For comparisons, use strict equality(`===`) and in-equality(`!==`) operators.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#>>_(Sign-propagating_right_shift). Also, understand that true is implicitly converted to a 1 because true=1 false=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `true` is implicitly converted to `1` in JavaScript (try `Number(true) + 1` in the console, this would yield `2`).

Moreover `>>` shifts the *bits* of a *number* to the right, discarding bits shifted off. Therefore `true >> 0` **does nothing except for implicitly converting** `true` to `1` (because no bits are shifted).

For the second example, `false` is implicitly converted to `0` and **because shifted bits are discarded, shifting doesn't have an effect on the result**. Try `false >> 1000`, it's still `0`.

---

Much better explanation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E_(Sign-propagating_right_shift)), thanks to @adam-beck, he also adds another very good point:

> If you don't know much about bit shifting, bitwise operators, or even working with binary numbers, know that when you shift ( >> or <<) by 0 you aren't changing the number at all: `152 >> 0 === 152`

Comment: I'm going to piggy-back this answer and post a link from my comment again: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#>>_(Sign-propagating_right_shift)

Comment: "implicimplicitlyely"

Comment: If you don't know much about bit shifting, bitwise operators, or even working with binary numbers, know that when you shift ( >> or <<) by 0 you aren't changing the number at all: `152 >> 0 === 152`. You can also even do the reverse of your question `152 >> false === 152`

Comment: hope you don't mind adding your comment to the answer @adam-beck, because I think it's valuable.

Comment: "In ES6" sounds like it wasn't before? Just write "JS".

Comment: "*try `true + 1`*" - rather not. If you want to know what the result of a conversion is, use `Number(true)` or `+true`.

Comment: Little side question, why does JavaScript convert the boolean rather than the Number when i do:  true + 1

Comment: because of +. If you wrote if(1){} then 1 would be convertrd to true